# Change image size when uploading with laravel file system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-filesystem

I want to change the size of an image i am uploading. 
I am using the built-in file system and i am storing it in the storage folder, and it is working great. but how can i manipulate its size?
the upload is like this:

```
$request->file('image')->store('images');
```

I know there is the Intervention-Image library but is there another way?
Thanks.

Comment: Intervention-Image is the best. So my suggestion is to use it.

Comment: There is no built-in feature?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature to resize images in Laravel.
I advise you to use **Intervention**, it's really easy to use.